# Why can't a generic member function in a class implementing an interface take an argument of the type of the class (instead of the interface)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Considering an interface `IDog` with the method `likes<T extends IDog>( other: T )`. The method takes an argument whose type extends the interface. Why is not allowed to implement that method in a derived class `Dog` using the class as type of the argument instead of the interface?

```
interface IDog
{
    likes<T extends IDog>( other: T ): boolean;
}

class Dog implements IDog
{
    private name = "Buddy";
    public likes<T extends Dog>( other: T )
        // ^^^^^
        // error: Property 'likes' in type 'Dog' is not 
        // assignable to the same property in base type 'IDog' [...]
        // Property 'name' is missing in type 'IDog' but required in type 'Dog'
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Removing the private property `name` would make the error go away but is not a solution for my real world problem. The weird thing is though, that the same example without generics works just fine:

```
interface ICat
{
    likes( other: ICat ): boolean;
}

class Cat implements ICat
{
    private name = "Simba";
    public likes( other: Cat )  // no error using Cat here (instead of ICat)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine that the compiler had no problem with the way you are implementing `IDog`.  Then the following would be fine:

```
class Dog implements IDog {
  private name = "Buddy";
  public likes<T extends Dog>(other: T) {
    return other.name.toUpperCase() === "FRIEND";
  }
}

const myDog: IDog = new Dog(); // should be okay if Dog implements IDog
```

But that can lead to runtime errors that would not be caught by the compiler:

```
const eyeDog: IDog = {
  likes(other) {
    return true;
  }
}
console.log(myDog.likes(eyeDog)) // okay for the compiler, but RUNTIME ERROR
```

So the compiler is right that `Dog` does not properly implement `IDog`. Allowing this would be ["unsound"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness).  If you have a function type you want to extend (make more specific), you cannot make its parameters more specific and be sound; you need to make them more *general*.  This means that function parameters should be checked [contravariantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_parameter_type) (that is, they vary the opposite way from the function type... they counter-vary... contravariant).

---

Of course that leads to your question about `Cat`.  Doesn't the exact same argument work there?

```
class Cat implements ICat {
  private name = "Simba";
  public likes(other: Cat) { // no error
    return other.name.toUpperCase() === "FRIEND";
  }
}
const myCat: ICat = new Cat(); // no error

const eyeCat: ICat = {
  likes(other) { return true; }
}

console.log(myCat.likes(eyeCat)) // no compiler error, but RUNTIME ERROR
```

Indeed it does!  The compiler is allowing the unsound extension of `ICat` with `Cat`.  What gives?

This is explicitly intentional behavior; method [parameters are checked *bivariantly*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), meaning the compiler will accept both wider parameter types (safe) and narrower parameter types (unsafe).  This is apparently because, in practice, people rarely write the sort of unsafe code above with `myCat` (or `myDog` for that matter), and such unsafeness is what allows a lot of useful type hierarchies to exist (e.g., TypeScript allows `Array<string>` to be a subtype of `Array<string | number>`).

---

So, wait, why does the compiler care about soundness with generic type parameters but not with method parameters?  Good question; I don't know that there's any "official" answer to this (although I might have a look through GitHub issues to see if someone in the TS team has ever commented on that).  In general, the soundness violations in TypeScript were considered carefully based on heuristics and real-world code.

My guess is that people usually want type safety with their generics (as evidenced by [microsoft/TypeScript#16368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16368)'s implementation of stricter checks for them), and specifically adding extra code to allow method parameter bivariance would be more trouble than it's worth.

You can disable the strictness check for generics by enabling [the `--noStrictGenericChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noStrictGenericChecks), but I wouldn't recommend intentionally making the compiler less type safe, since it will affect much more than your `Dog` issue, and it's hard to find resources for help when you rely on unusual compiler flags.

---

Note that you may be looking for the pattern where each subclass or implementing class can only `likes()` parameters of its own type and not every possible subtype.  If so, then you might consider using [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) instead.  When you use `this` as a type, it's like a generic type that means "whatever type the subclass calling this method is".  But it's specifically made to allow the kind of thing you seem to be doing:

```
interface IGoldfish {
  likes(other: this): boolean;
}

class Goldfish implements IGoldfish {
  private name = "Bubbles";
  public likes(other: this) {
    return other.name.toUpperCase() === "FRIEND";
  }
}
const myFish: IGoldfish = new Goldfish();
```

This, of course, has the same problem as the other two examples:

```
const eyeFish: IGoldfish = { likes(other) { return true; } }
console.log(myFish.likes(eyeFish)) // RUNTIME ERROR
```

so it's not a panacea for unsoundness.  But it is very similar to the generic version without the generic parameter warning.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBED2BzZBvAKGWQBtgBrCAZwB4AVZCAD0hABMq0tsA+ACkxgAFtABcyOgEpxAI0yYSEOCADcBAL4ECCEnCqduyYAFsADouMRwnDDnxFkpqMABucSMhBxLyALzIAIgAhAFc2NgBPALViUxCZMgRSCmp6RhYrDmRufkERKHEpe2JiKAgwEKgQZDzoADovSzqwTABVU1NoAGE9CD5JP19-AIAxACVUAFEAOXRoh01NbUwQKjBGCIhucVtcf0JiMkoqAWFoAYOSsoqq5DAoEIgY5EXl1fXjCO2uO38QCAA7tkcP0VMgAPTg5BUISYEIkNjIGQoTDkOARIwwYG4EzmCCWaw-bAEe4Yy4IFZUBQQOokEGfbi0lInCCbbiSAaQ5BwEhU6Gw+GI5E1NERAA0SJC6zGrWmdFQAFlJshJmMxgB5MYaZAIdwIITIPgQC46ynU2kg40vLRaUCQWCIFCoHrrS5HainfI7F3SJHyRTKNRLHR6TguoxmCxWMA2cOXJyudwoRooYYAZRMMjg81i8USyWOnrEyB9xSu5Uq1VqUAa3hpLXanSgPSofQGQ2G4ymsxz1uDlPWrIgLu97j8ZfdJ2rJuulbuDyefbea2QnxHaHDf0BJfcoIhUJhcIRSJRosxO-WuKjhOd7hJUDJDgpq3NdOwfDX7iZhaHPs5UJ5PlD0FE8RXRCUZClZAZTlRVlVVDUtXUHU9QNI0TWfKlFAtd8rSWW1wGgeAkDQABxBQ2BgYAYQnZkiwKO4hGo305GpQMNC0EN9GQciESomir3xaMbF4yjqINeNnDcDwU3HYJ4gSaheziBJgCSSd6PEYRmLLUoK1uatayaBsOm6Xp+kGTsJhmOZnleZdB02EZxJ2UT+INfYCw9ad8GQWdbnuR4wWQzRMI+CJnJhVyKPc8d-iBNzxNBe9H2ITDX3pCLxO-D0h0ioQOX3bleUwfkjyFU9wMlaVZXlJUVTVTVtV1MB9UNK08FNF9sLfdDrQIIA)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine such a situation: you have

```
const myDog: Dog
const someOtherDog: IDog
```

and such a function:

```
function seeIfLikes(dog: IDog, anotherDog: IDog) {
  return dog.likes(anotherDog)
}
```

This function seems OK, `IDog.likes()` wants something that extends `IDog` as the argument.

But when you call `seeIfLikes(myDog, someOtherDog)`, something unexpected happens: `myDog` is casted to an `IDog`, so TypeScript will forget that its `likes()` method requires something that extends `Dog`, not `IDog`!

So this function call will pass the type checking even if `someOtherDog` does not actually extend `Dog` - and if your `Dog.likes()` contains some code specific to the `Dog` class, not to `IDog`, you get a runtime kaboom.

This is why we cannot add new generic parameter restriction in subtypes: they may be casted to their supertypes, and that restriction will be gone. Hope this is clear enough to understand.

---

Yes, that `Cat` example will suffer from exactly the same problem, but tsc let it pass for unknown reason. Maybe it is a limitation of the type system, or a bug that is better reported.

Comment: But why is the Cat example working then? The same thing you did coud be done with cats: `const seeIfLikes = ( cat1: ICat, cat2: ICat ) => cat2.likes( cat1 );`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement `IDog` interface you need to make sure that `likes` method is assignable to `likes` method of the `IDog` interface, right?

Consider this example:

```js
declare var dog: (arg: {}) => boolean

declare var idog: (arg: { name: string }) => boolean

dog = idog // error

idog = dog // ok
```

You are unable to assign `idog` function to `dog` function because `idog` implementation is allowed to use `name` parameter whether `dog` implementation is not.

You may think, it is strange, since this is works as expected:

```js
declare var iarg: { name: string }
declare var arg: {}

iarg = arg // error, because iarg uses `name` and arg does not have this property
arg = iarg
```

Object with more properties is assignable to object with less properties, it is intuitive.

In your example, the issue happens, because function types contra-variant with their parameter types. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) for more context.

Now, try to disable `strictFunctionTypes` flag. You will see that this code will compile:

```js
let dog = (arg: {}) => true

let idog = (arg: { name: string }) => {
    console.log(arg.name)
    return true
}

dog = idog // ok
```

Let's go back to the original issue with generics:

```js
let dog = <T extends {}>(arg: T) => true

let idog = <T extends { name: string }>(arg: T) => true

dog = idog // error
idog = dog
```

Even without `strictFunctionTypes` flag, this code still produces an error. Despite the fact that function argument positions are treated bivariantly (without strictFunctionTypes), I think generics  still treated contravariantly. I might be wrong so I will be happy if somebody will correct me.

This means that typescript will try to check if `T extends {}` is assigned to `T extends { name: string }` despite the fact that we are trying to assign `T extends { name: string }` to `T extends {}`