# why type `Record<string,unknown>` does not accept object with defined keys as value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to have a function within type that can accept any object as input. I've defined it like

```
type Props = { onSubmit: (data: Record<string, unknown>) => void};
```

but when I try to pass this type to it

```
type SignIn = (data: {email: string, password: string}) => void;
```

I get this error

```
Type 'SignIn' is not assignable to type '(data: Record<string, unknown>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type '{ email: string; password: string; }': email, password
```

Full example of the error is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgcwHYEklQLxQBQBMCGw+AXFAN4QC2+cANqQM7ABOcSCANFGPgwwO4B7ZrkYs2CAL4BKTAD4oAN0FxcAbgBQAY0FImUBolRJS8ZGkw4K1Olx58hImfPJQdewbQgA6WoITYVDS0drwCwriykpoaoJBQAArMgmAMlmRQujAArgBGlHDApHiEJFAAShA6IgA8TKzsXNlIANZIgvxIcrIYCsqq0dq6+ll5BUWJyanpo-mFjEZo0UA)

Funny [this works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAuE8AcFMAIGUCWBzAdgSVbAvLAFACYCGoRAXLAN7QC2RiANhQM6gBOiqyANLJEc2YB3APZsCLdp2QBfAJQ4AfLABuIxAQDcAKBABjEalaxmKDKgpI0mHPmp1GvfoNHj5SqrANGRDaADoGEWQ8WnoGJwFhMQIFGR1tCBhYAAU2EUhmW0pYQ3gAVwAjGkRQCkISclgAJWgDcQAeVg4uXnzUAGtUESFURQVsZTUNeO1vYzyikrLU9MzsyeLS8vtwyJcY90HPcd8AoJCwxz4o11jYGXigA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example could be reduced to this:

```js
declare var signin: (data: { email: string, password: string }) => void
declare var record: (data: Record<string, unknown>) => void

signin = record
record = signin // error
```

This is even more interesting if you will check assignability of arguments. You will see that assignability is reversed.

```js
declare var signinArg: { email: string, password: string }
declare var recordArg: Record<string, unknown>

signinArg = recordArg // error
recordArg = signinArg
```

Why `signin` is not assignable to `record` but `signinArg` is assignable to `recordArg`.

The answer is:
Functions in typescript are contra-variant to their arguments. This is by design.

More about covariance in TypeScript you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc)

Try to disable `strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag. You will see that error is gone.

Previously, all functions was bivariant and it wasn't safe.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681526/why-cant-a-generic-member-function-in-a-class-implementing-an-interface-take-an/68682276#68682276) you can find very similar question with more context of the problem

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, it would be nice to have this in TS documentation I found only this reference https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types

Answer (score 0):

A broad type(`Record<string, unknown>`) cannot be assigned to a specific type(`{ email: string, password: string }`), while the reverse is possible.

```
type SignIn = (data: Record<string, unknown>) => void;
const signIn: SignIn = ({ email, password }) => { console.log(email, password) };

type Data = { email: string, password: string }
type Props = {
    onSubmit: (data: Data) => void
};
const onSubmit: Props = { onSubmit: signIn };
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgcwHYEklQLxQBQBMCGw+AXFAEoQDGA9gE64A8AzsLXEggDRQCuSA1kmoB3JAD4AlJjFQAbtTi4A3ACgaSFlCaJUSUvGRpMOAN5QIAW3xwANtzD4mTYXVxQAvlIwyz6ptRsIADobagRsS2s7KAcnF3opd1UVUEgoABFCfGMzSNtSFjYOe0dnVwLWdgQPFPBoAAVaajAmHJUoDqhqJBgeACMLOGBSPCzSTKIvGXlFFSS1bs1u3oGh0kbm1qwzZf7B4a0dIySgA)

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be also tackled with generics like this

```
type SignInData = {email: string, password: string};
type SignIn = (data: SignInData) => void;
const signIn: SignIn = async ({email, password}) => { console.log(email, password) };

type Props<DATA extends Record<string, unknown>> = { onSubmit: (data: DATA) => void};

const onSubmit: Props<SignInData> = {onSubmit: signIn};
```