# How to implement an interface with unknown generic properties?

Tags: typescript, generics, arguments, typescript-generics

In our project we have an interface like this:

```
export interface InterfaceA {
  closed: EventEmitter<unknown>;
}
```

Then we use it in components like this:

```
export interface CloseData {
  closeSource: CloseSource;
}
export class ComponentB implements InterfaceA {
  closed = new EventEmitter<CloseData>();
...
}
```

With "CloseSource" being an enum.

It works great except when we enable the "**strictFunctionTypes**" flag (or the "**strict**" one) we get this error:

> error TS2416: Property 'closed' in type 'ComponentB' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'InterfaceA'.
> Type 'EventEmitter' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter'.
> Types of property 'observers' are incompatible.
> Type 'Observer[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer[]'.
> Type 'Observer' is not assignable to type 'Observer'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CloseData'.

From what I found (here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68711655), it's because of the **contra-variance** of functions.

First, I don't get the logic behind this.

Second, what can we do to make it right?
We don't want to use "**any**" since our code quality analyser tool tells us it's bad, and we don't want to disable a flag that seems to make our code safer.

Is there a magic solution?

Here is an [example typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQG4FMB2NkmDGdKOAXzgDMoIQ4ByAAQENMBzAVwBtGoB6AY2jpaAbgBQ40egAekWHCxsaAYQ4QAzugDKENlD7pEouHCUAZAPKbkAfQBCAFQBycALx0+qjbZiZaAGiMTc0cAMQBJACUAWTsnV3cITHJgKBBvXwDjJQBBRyVkU1jnN1o+Zn0OdP9As0sbMKVg+NLPdDCBDMDzADVkCNNsgE1miAwoLgBPaqyLK2tkXsd7Zo91dDQsGGqScWlZeGBsInJGfRNWgBFGGEZDY2NVjW1dfQAuc7XnvXQxHdEeHhwADqAAtrnBgGo4HxdFBNhwJnA2BoACaSGTQA5HKAnM5hbG49DZO73R7oFHvDbYXD4QhQAA8zAmAD5fuj9tCuGooUpqJBMJtiaAwBx0CBNlD8XTCcSEIEHq0UfEBQB3FAYal4AhEekqNZXG7MgAUAEo2f8eKDwWE4DAoMBybaIHAUc6YM61O6wEi1IcWHAAERMgPszEQgmnAxS46R2wkhVrCnqzY07UMtiYADWmAgKswrNEOz2YY8jG5Jj5iU2ceFovF2ElEf0cbl905ieV6DVVJwWrpusu10YxrNhfEAKt8AEnCVKugmfDtpBBnIbBgunQobkh2lkbg0ZxkaU9OWbiZzPj7dRlI1vdpOvsBaLGLkpfLvPAVewSgh4DrEv3Jt0B-VtSUVTtu1vVN+z1DQDWHU02SAA)

The solution C is not perfect since there is still one "any" but it's a step in the right direction I think (we can try asking people using our lib to add the generics whenever they can).
Is there any way to make the code work without "any" and without changing the ComponentC (or A) class?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wQK1Am) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: `EventEmitter<T>` is apparently *invariant* in `T` so `T extends U` implies neither `EventEmitter<T> extends EventEmitter<U>` nor the reverse.  If you want *safety*, then you cannot just write `InterfaceA` without specifying the generic explicitly; the only thing that works is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpDPBm).  If you want *lack of compiler errors*, then `any` is what you need, because it is explicitly meant to loosen such restrictions.  I'm happy to write this up as an answer, but...

Comment: ...the part where you say "I don't get the logic behind this" seems like you should probably elaborate on why not.   There are plenty of SO q/a about contravariance of function inputs like [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/63786868/2887218) or [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/58458982/2887218),  and articles like [this](//www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) that explain what's going on, and I'm not sure if you actually want another one spelled out for you in the answer.